# .php~ in file extension after exiting vim editor

Tags: php, linux, vim, file-extension

This may be a dumb question but I can't seem to figure out why a php file with the same name is created but with extension `index.php~` after I finish editing `index.php` file on my remote server using vim.

I quit the vim editor with `:wq!` command, on Windows the `~` in file extension usually mean unsaved or file that is currently opened, is it the same thing on Linux server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.php~** is backup and contains a file as it was before you edited **index.php**

You can disable this behavior in your **.vimrc** file:

```
set nobackup
```